# Unable to print name of uploaded file using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am using the following code to upload a file using html and java servlet.

However I am not able to print the location or retrieve the value of the path where file is uploaded.

Please help me out as to how I can print that. I want to print for example: `d:/new/filename` in my servlet file.
Thanks in advance. Below is my code snippet:

```
**index.html**

<html>  
<body>  
<form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html> 

**UploadServlet.java**

import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;  

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");  
out.print("successfully uploaded");  
}  
}   


***web.xml***

<web-app>  

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>UploadServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
out.print("successfully uploaded in" + m.getFilesystemName("fname"));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19644121)

Comment: @JP.Aulet is it better?